# Another simplification problem with algebraic indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please help me with some steps for how to solve this question?

$ \frac {3^{n} + 3^{n+2}} {3^{n-1} - 3^{n-2}}$

The answer is 45 apparently. I need to simplify to get to this answer.

If someone could give me a hint how to start off I would love to give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry - I need to simplify it which will result in the answer 45. I think it means the n's will eventually cancel out..? It is possible my text could have a mistake with the question and/or answer

Comment: @rogerl $9 - 3 \ne 8$.

Comment: @qaphla An excellent point. Thanks. Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac {3^{n} + 3^{n+2}} {3^{n-1} - 3^{n-2}} \equiv \require{cancel} \frac{\cancel{3^n}[1+3^2]}{\cancel{3^n}[3^{-1}-3^{-2}]}=\frac{10}{\left[\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}\right]}=\frac{10}{\left[\frac{3}{9}-\frac{1}{9}\right]}=\frac{10}{\left[ \frac{2}{9}\right]}=10 \cdot \left[\frac{9}{2}\right]$$

### $$=\color{green}{\boxed{45}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't understand why my brain just can't get questions of this style! I am actually usually really good with algebra and this sort of thing :(

Comment: Sure. Remember that the key here is to factor out the $3^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

You can start by writing $\displaystyle\frac{3^n+3^{n+2}}{3^{n-1}-3^{n-2}}=\frac{3^n(1+3^2)}{3^{n-2}(3-1)}$.